# Check code for Domain Dictionary rules in Visual Studio or Resharper

Tags: visual-studio, domain-driven-design, resharper, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

I need some kind of plugin or ReSharper's plugin/custom pattern for making my code strict against some dictionary.

For example, we have to synonyms: currency, asset, cash. We want to force all developers to use only 'currency' word. And replace all synonyms with 'currency'. How to show some hint or warning about this situation for them?

Do you know any good ways to make the dictionary and use it inside visual studio?

Comment: This could be done easily with an NDepend rule based on the method GetWords() have a look at this article related to your question https://blog.ndepend.com/checking-ddd-ubiquitous-language-with-ndepend/